# How to prevent numbers from getting too low/high in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm currently working on a "Hunger Games"-Simulator and every player has 17 traits. The traits of the winning person get changed the least and the traits of the worst person get changed much. But after I change the traits they often go below zero or above 1000 (should be max) even though I even coded a backup for this.

I already tried to just set them back into the range 1-1000 and give the leftover trait-points to another trait. It also just happens after **multiple iterations**.

#### This is the code to change the traits:

*List "**pl**" is looking like this: **[trait1, trait2, ..., trait18]***

*"**count**" is the **rank**.*

```
while again == True:
            for k in range(int(count/2)):
                randnum = random.randint(0,20)
                randnum2 = random.randint(0,15)
                randnum3 = random.randint(0,15)
                pl[randnum2] += randnum
                pl[randnum3] -= randnum
            for y in pl:
                if y > 1000:
                    over = abs(y - 1000)
                    randnum = random.randint(0,15)
                    if pl[randnum] > 1000 - over:
                        break
                    else:
                        y = 1000
                        pl[random.randint(0,15)] += over
                if y < 0:
                    over = abs(y)+1
                    randnum = random.randint(0,15)
                    if pl[randnum] < over:
                        break
                    else:
                        y = 1
                        pl[randnum] -= over
            for y in pl:
                if y > 1000 or y < 1:
                    again = True
                    break
                else:
                    again = False
```

I expected that the traits get updated so that if you add all trait-points together you always get the same result with every player. But it seems like they either get **really big or really small** and don't have the same sum all the time.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use special list-like class with method:

```
def __setitem__(self, name, value):
    if minValue < value < maxValue:
        super().__setitem__(name, value)
```

and define other methods (`__add__`, `append`, ...) using that